# Storing a boolean result in a variable using the Python WebDriver for Pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, pytest

I'm exporting my test cases from the Selenium IDE to Python & using a script to convert them from Unittest to Py.test.  While making some manual changes, I stumbled across an issue I need a solution to.

In the IDE, I have a scenario where I visit a page within a WebUI, store that web pages contents, & verify if certain driver exists:

```
storeBodyText  |  myBody  |     
storeEval      |  javascript{storedVars['myBody'].search("driver-video");}  |  isVideo
```

From here, I visit a Settings page and check that certain options exists.  If the video driver was found in the code above, then a link for that option should exist on the Settings page.  If not, then the link won't appear and I don't need to verify that it exists.  I handle that in the IDE as follows:

```
if  |  storedVars['isVideo']!=-1
       waitForText  |  link=Display  |  Display
endIf
```

I then export my code using the **'Python / unittest / WebDriver'** and run a conversion script I created, which converts the unittest code to Py.test.  This leaves my with the following associated code:

```
myBody = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("BODY").text
# ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [getEval | javascript{storedVars['myBody'].search("driver-video");} | ]]
.
.
.
# ERROR: Caught exception [unknown command [if]]
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.LINK_TEXT, "Display"), "Display")
    )
#         for i in range(60):
#             try:
#                 if "Display" == driver.find_element_by_link_text("Display").text: break
#             except: pass
#             time.sleep(1)
#         else: self.fail("time out")

# ERROR: Caught exception [unknown command [endIf]]
```

The errors are not from my script.  The errors existed as a result of exporting the test case to 'Python / unittest / WebDriver.'  Totally expected, of course, being that I used java script to perform the action.  Now, I'm trying to convert this to Py.test and perform the same action as I was doing in the Selenium IDE.  I'm looking for a way to...

1. Store the results of the search for **'driver-video'** driver, which will be of some boolean value.  I'd like a way, if possible, to store this result directly into a variable, if possible.  Something that might look like or come close to looking like...

i.e.

```
isVidPres = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(
               assert re.search("^[\s\S]*driver-video[\s\S]*$",driver.find_element_by_css_selector("myBody").text
)
```

2. Use that boolean variable to determine if I need to verify that a 'Display' link should exist or not.

I'm open to using a try/catch loop if necessary, but would like to perform this action without it if possible.  Does anyone know how to perform this action?  Thanks ahead of time to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this issue on my own.  Thought it might be a good idea to post it in case someone else comes across this issue while tasked with exporting Selenese code to **Python/unittest/Web Driver** and then converting that to **Py.test** code.

For searching the page to verify if certain drivers exist, I used the following code:

```
        systemPage = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("BODY").text

        if re.match("^[\s\S]*xorg-driver-video-intel[\s\S]*$", systemPage):
            isVideoPres = True
        else:
            isVideoPres = False
```

The driver is stored in a table, but the location of the driver [if installed] in the table is not guaranteed to be in the same location.  Therefore, I stored the contents of the page & performed a regular expressions search for the name of the driver.

For the section where I verify the associated link exists if the driver is installed, I used the following code:

```
        if isVideoPres == True:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.LINK_TEXT, "Display"), "Display")
            )
        elif isVideoPres == False:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Display"))
            )
```

In this code, I check to see if the video driver was found.  If so, I verify that the link taking me to the "Display" settings is available for the user to click on.  If the driver wasn't found, then I verify the link is not in existence on the settings page.